# cannot pass argument to a simple javascript function

Tags: javascript

The code below the _______________ works as is. It creates a table. I append a button at the end of each row (see .insertAdjacentHTML below) that calls the restart() function.

However, if I do the following: onclick="restart('Restarted')" and then add a parameter to the function restart, like directly below, it does not work.

All of this is happening in one .js file.

```
function restart(msg) {
   alert(msg);
}

//____________________________________________________

function restart() {
   alert('Restarted');
}

//Add the data rows.
for (var i = 1; i < uuts.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < uutCount; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = uuts[i][j];
    }
cell.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin','<button  \ 
     onclick="restart()">Restart</button>');
```

Comment: You have two functions named `restart()`.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? Have you tried escaping the parameter? Ex: `'<button onclick="restart(\'Restarted\')">Restart</button>'`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: OK I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly escape your quotes:

```
.insertAdjacentHTML('<button onclick="restart(\'Restarted\')">Restart</button>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your function exists in the scope? Depending on how your code is, you can try and attach it to window (or whatever other scope you have) with something like:

```
window.restart = function(msg){ alert(msg); }
```

[Fiddle showing it off in a simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/x1v489sg/1/)